# I have a JTable and its TableModel, it works well but what I want to do now is to get the selected cells of it

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

I have a `JTable` and its `TableModel`, it works well but what I want to do now is to get the selected cells of it and after changes made write the same to a textfile.

i thought of doing something like this

```
private void btnupateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt1){

    dtm = (DefaultTableModel)myjtable.getModel();

    int col=dtm.getColumnCount(); 
    int selectedRow=myjtable.getSelectedRow();

    try{
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\WINNT\\PROFILES\\palanisamyp\\workspace\\InventoryDBInfile.\\Myfile.txt")); 

        for(int i=0;i<selectedRow;i++) {  
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
                String data=(String) dtm.getValueAt(i,j);               
                dtm.setValueAt(data, i, j);
                  out.write(data+"|");   
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What's the problem/question? 2)From the looks of you looping, it looks like you're only writing data up until the row selected. Is that what you want?

Comment: @peeskillet-ya you are write but before writing to the file i want user to edit a cell and change the value and that entire row i want to write to a file.apology for less information

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).